# Fast datastore for logging

Tags: logging, nosql, node.js

I'm currently writing a questionnaire which gathers and stores a lot of data from different users and I'm looking into a way of efficiently storing the results. I have the following requirements :

- really fast write
- persistent
- usable from node.js
- small overhead
- no read authorized before storing the data (for performance sake, I need write-only)

Each user can `POST` several results which I'll need to query by user id at a later point in time. Those requests will be handled by different node.js processes running in parallel. In the end, the data might look like:

```
user1:
  result1
  result2
  result3
user2:
  result1
user3:
  result1
  result2
```

And basically I'd need to be able to :

- Get the list of users
- Query the results from a given user

I first thought I'd use a file per user, but I'm afraid this won't scale as there could potentially be more users than the maximum allowed number of files.

Any suggestions ?

**Edit** : each result would be small, typically less than 50kb, if this might help.

**Edit 2** : each result fits on a single ASCII line (no `\n` in the data), otherwise the data should just be considered as a string with no particular structure.

Comment: So which data store did you decide to use? Can you provide some insight as to why you chose that particular DBMS?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A key value pair db like redis would help  you. It can use used from node.js and you can query users with user id if you use userid as they key.

But more importantly.. Do you need performance or do you need to scale? :)

--Sai

Comment: I really love redis, but it's not suited here, it's an overkill (I don't need any of the data structures). I need both performance (in writing) and scaling.

Comment: I just gave redis as example for a KV db.. But you can choose any KV DB. Even Berkley DB or Tokyo Cabinet. And scaling you need to plan for it. Node and DB like redis gives  you performance at best and perceived scaling...

Comment: "any kv db" is not really the answer I was looking for…

Comment: An architecture diagram perhaps :).. The data access pattern you are looking for points to a KV DB type. I can't give you a definite database and force your to use it as you need to benchmark them for your usage pattern. DBs are intricate entities. Sorry if I can't be point you one DB and ask you to use it.

Comment: I understand your point but I was more looking for a datastore specifically aimed at fast writes, I don't need the overhead of high level functionalities

Comment: What is the safety level you are looking for? A DB which writes data in memory should be fast like Memcached. But using it in single server mode is a recipe for disaster for safety. If you are not looking at safety at the moment, the highest write speed you will get by using a in memory hash in JS :)

Comment: I need safety (the application gathers data which has to be stored for further analysis), thus writing to the disk. Unfortunately I have access to only one server, so the application and storage must reside in the same place…

Comment: One way to address write performance and still retain high availability is to use HA or replication to ensure that even if your primary database goes down, a replicated database is available to take over the load. Berkeley DB Java Edition (http://bit.ly/dM4Qtw) provides both, very fast, light weight, write persistence and replication, should you need it, to ensure high availability and read load balancing.

Comment: Even though this isn't the road I took, it's the most complete answer imho.

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised that no one hasn't tipped of an append only dbms like Couchdb.

As the writes only goes to the end of the database file, its not only very fast but also very robust.
. Querying it is not a problem either as you have views (which you write in js). Talking to Couchdb is also quite simple from any language as you do it with REST/http.

Under some simple write bench I made I managed to utilize 100% of 10 cores, by inserting from several servers, which I think is quite powerful

I wouldn't use Tokyo Cabinet as the developing of it has officially stopped, in favor of Kyoto Cabinet

That's my 2cents

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why this has to be NoSQL... Consider using SQLite instead of files. It's very fast, very durable, easy to query (SQL). It's a good fit for node, as node is single-threaded and SQLite is an in-process database.

Here's an API to access SQLite from node: http://code.google.com/p/node-sqlite/

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [Elasticsearch](http://elasticsearch.org).  HTTP/JSON API, Lucene-backed, completely distributed.  I've stored hundreds of TiB of data in it.  It's even the default persistence for [logstash](http://logstash.net), a common tool used for exactly what you are/were looking to do.